# python create celery task job

Tags: python, parallel-processing, celery

lets say i have a python programm whitch i want to run always max 10 times in parallel using celery / rabbigmq and if some of the process finish i want to know about it so i can start a new process. how can i do so? some examples would be nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving an example is difficult as messaging is a bit complex, but what you can do basically is:

- rewrite your program to be a task or write a task that calls your program using subprocess
- configure celery to have 10 workers
- execute as many tasks as you need to get your job done, Celery will add them to its queue
- Celery will do the rest for you, once a task finished, another one is started till the queue is empty

Alternatively, if your want to start a task manually after one finished, you can configure Celery to send a message after its finished (I didn't try it yet, but have a look at CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND) You can then consume these messages and start your task.